# Help with Marketing cloud Data model

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I am trying to find the data model for Marketing cloud on Salesforce help website but haven't had any success yet. Can someone give point me in the right direction?

Comment: You should try the [marketing cloud trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/mrkt_cloud_basics). Its designed to give an overview of the platform, its data types, and its features.

Comment: A little more insight to your inquiry might help the community help more.

Answer (score 2):

I've written an eBook that explains the different data models used in Marketing Cloud, along with considerations and best practices for using each model. You can download this resource for free from https://www.getstride.com/datahandbook

Comment: Link not currently working.